# Is there a simpler way to traverse relationships to update cross object fields?

Tags: trigger, map, pricebook

I have a trigger that works but it seems like there should be a better and simpler way to accomplish the result. I have a custom object that is a child of Quote and has a lookup to Product2. I am tasked with getting the price from the PricebookEntry table using the standard price and inserting it into a field on Part__c. The solution I came up with was a map for the Part__c custom Object, a map for PricebookEntry, and a couple of maps to use as connectors with the key in both connector maps being the shared Product2Id.

```
trigger PartSetUnitPrice on Part__c (after insert) {
// When Part record is created retrieve the price of the Product and populate the Unit Price field using the Standard Pricebook.

// collections
Map<Id, Part__c> mapPart = new Map<Id, Part__c>();
Map<Id, PricebookEntry> mapPBE = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>(); 
Map<Id, Id> mapProductIdPartId = new Map<Id, Id>(); // key will be ProductId, value Part__c.Id
Map<Id, Id> mapProductIdPBEId= new Map<Id, Id>();  // key will be ProductId, PricebookEntryId
Map<Id, Double> mapUnitPrice = new Map<Id, Double>(); 

Set<Id> setOpptyId = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> setPartId = new Set<Id>(); 
Set<Id> setPBEId = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> setProduct2Id = new Set<Id>(); 

for(Part__c p : Trigger.new) {
    setPartId.add(p.Id);
}

mapPart.putAll([SELECT Id, Quote__r.OpportunityId, Part__r.Id // Part__r.Id == Product2Id
                FROM Part__c
                WHERE Id IN : setPartId]);

for(Id key : mapPart.keySet()) {
    setProduct2Id.add(mapPart.get(key).Part__r.Id);
    mapProductIdPartId.put(mapPart.get(key).Part__r.Id,key); // pair Product2Id to Part__c.Id
}

for(Id key : mapPart.keySet()) {
    setOpptyId.add(mapPart.get(key).Quote__r.OpportunityId);
}

mapPBE.putAll([SELECT Id, UnitPrice, Product2Id 
             FROM PricebookEntry
             WHERE Product2Id IN : setProduct2Id
             AND Pricebook2.IsStandard = true]);    

for(Id key : mapPBE.keySet()) {
    mapProductIdPBEId.put(mapPBE.get(key).Product2Id,key); //Pair Product2Id to PricebookEntryId
}    

// Variables to put UnitPrice on Part__c
Double dblUnitPrice;
Id idProd;
Id idPBE;

// Iterate over mapPart map to put PricebookEntry.UnitPrice on Part__c.Unit_Price__c
for(Id key : mapPart.keySet()) {
    idProd = mapPart.get(key).Part__r.Id; // get Product2Id from Part__c.Id
    idPBE = mapProductIdPBEId.get(idProd); // get PricebookEntryId from Product2Id
    dblUnitPrice = mapPBE.get(idPBE).UnitPrice;  // get UnitPrice from PricebookEntryId
    mapUnitPrice.put(key,dblUnitPrice);
}

// Commit to database
List<Part__c> listPart = new List<Part__c>(); // List to hold Quote SObject for update
Set<Id> sPartId = new Set<Id>(); // Set to de-dupe the list else duplicate Id error fires on update
for(Part__c p: Trigger.new) {
    if(!sPartId.contains(p.Id)){ // Logical complement operator. Inverts the value of a Boolean, so that true becomes false, and false becomes true.
        Part__c part = new Part__c();
        part.Id = p.Id;
        part.Unit_Price__c = mapUnitPrice.get(p.Id);
        listPart.add(part);
        sPartId.add(p.Id);

    }
}
update listPart;
}
```

Is this a common approach or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (assumes a uni-currency org; adapt as needed for multicurrency)

```
// Build list of Product2Ids to use as search key in PBE
Set<ID> prodIdSet = new Set<ID> ();
for (Part__c p: Trigger.new)
  prodIdSet.add(p.part__c);  // build PBE search key list

// Build map of Product2Id to PBE (Unitprice)
Map<ID,Pricebookentry> prodIdToPbeMap = new map<ID,Pricebookentry>();
for (PricebookEntry pbe: [select id, product2Id, unitprice
                           from pricebookentry
                           where product2Id IN : prodIdSet and
                           pricebook2.isStandard = true])
 prodIdToPbeMap.put(pbe.product2Id,pbe);

// Go thru trigger list and update each item with unitprice from map
List<Part__c> pUpdList = new List<Part__c>();
for (Part__c p: Trigger.new)
   pUpdList.add(
     new Part__c(id = p.id,
                 unitPrice__c = prodIdToPbeMap.get(p.part__c).unitPrice));

update pUpdList;
```

Comment: Very neat and compact. FYI there is a missing right round bracket to close the new Part__c statement (second to last line). Thank you!

Comment: @arabianrhino - thanks for pointing out the syntax error and 'self-curing'